# create a regular expression to match only the first word of a sentence, when it is equal to or greater than 4 characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a regular expression to match only the first word of a sentence, when it is equal to or greater than 4 characters. I searched for truth and forums here and could not do it as ..

Example:

```
"Christmas Baskets"> "Christmas"
"Tea and infusions"> "Tea and infusions"
"Beer"> "Beer"
```

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this. Use `strpos` to find the first space in the string - if there's none, or if it's in position 5 or below, print the whole string. Otherwise, using `substr` to extract just the relevant parts.

Comment: And what should it match if the first word is less than four characters? You seem to want to return the whole sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but this should give the output you've described:

```
function get_first_word_or_sentence($sentence)
{
    $word = strtok($sentence, ' ');

    return strlen($word) >= 4 ? $word : $sentence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange use of RegEx.  The following will only match a word at the beginning of a sentence that is longer than 3 characters:

```
/^[^\s][^\s][^\s][^\s]+/
```

Comment: good idea, but you can write the same like this `^\S{4,}` and this can't check if it is letters.